# How to create a varibale range in an index function?

Tags: excel

I'm using this formula below to retrieve an array of dates from a specific sheet:

=INDEX(indirect("'"&CONCATENATE(I$2," ","Sub Tasks")&"'!$**H**$2:$**H**$2385"))

(the cell **I$2** refers the sheet initials, all of the sheets has the name "C# Sub Tasks" such as "C1 Sub Tasks", "C2 Sub Tasks"....Ci Sub Tasks etc)

Each sheet has several columns, all with the same cell ranges (2:2385).
The only difference is of course the column letter ("H" in the case above)

I'd like to make the range $H$2:$H$2385 dynamic, so i could switch between columns based on a condition. let's say that If cell A2 = "*End date*", the letter "*H*" will be replaced by "**G**".

I've tried CONCATENATE and INDIRECT, and well, it didn't work.

Any ideas ?

Comment: what version of Excel?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ADDRESS` function and `VLOOKUP` to determine the column.
I hard coded the array as an array constant within the formula, but you could also set up a table and refer to it by cell reference:

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2,VLOOKUP($A$2,{"End Date",7;"Start Date",6;0,8},2,FALSE),,,$I$2&" SubTasks")&":"&ADDRESS(2385,VLOOKUP($A$2,{"End Date",7;"Start Date",6;0,8},2,FALSE))),1,1)
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for the quick response !. I'm still half way through, the outcome of the formula is a single result, and I need the whole array (between 2 - 2385). I've tried to make an array formula, but only got errors.

Comment: Edit: I've failed to mention I'm using Google Speardsheets, so curly brackets = ARRAYFORMULA. anyway, the formula is now something of: (INDEX(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2,VLOOKUP($A$2,ARRAYFORMULA("סטטוס ביצוע",6,"Start Date",6,0,6),2,FALSE),,,$I$2&" Sub Tasks")&":"&ADDRESS(2385,VLOOKUP($A$2,ARRAYFORMULA("סטטוס ביצוע",6,"Start Date",6,0,6),2,FALSE))),1,1)). Now I'm getting a #REF Error, It's says the VLOOKUP is out of range.

Comment: @DoronA Just remove the INDEX function. INDIRECT should expand the array automatically unless you have data where it will need to expand.  I only used INDEX because you had it in your example (although incorrectly, at least for Excel) And in the future, it would be wise to tag your questions with the program you are actually using. If you don't know how to create an array constant in sheets, just use an equivalent lookup table and insert the cell references into the formula.